# Java Streams, filter only the first 'N' matches

Tags: java

is there any way to filter only the first 'n' matches using java streams?

for example, if we have this code:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("zero","one","two","three","four","five","one","one");

List<String> filteredWords = words.stream()
                .filter(word->!word.equals("one"))//filter all "one" strings..
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(filteredWords);
```

this will filter all "one" strings from the word stream.

So, how to filter **only** the first 'n' matches and keep the rest of the stream intact?

in other words, if n=1 then, the program should output

```
"zero","two","three","four","five","one","one"
```

if n=2 then

"zero","two","three","four","five","one"

Comment: No, because stream predicates should be stateless. Just call `remove("one")` n times instead (on a mutable list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class doing the filtering for you

```
class LimitedFilter<T> implements Predicate<T> {
    int matches = 0;
    final int limit;
    private Predicate<T> delegate;
    public LimitedFilter<T>(Predicate<T> p, int limit) { 
        delegate = p; this.limit = limit;
    }
    public boolean test(T toTest) {
        if (matches > limit) return true;
        boolean result = delegate.test(toTest);
        if (result) matches++;
        return result;
    }
}
```

and then use it to filter

```
Predicate<String> limited = new LimitedFilter<>(w -> !"one".equals(w), 5);
List<String> filteredWords = words.stream()
            .filter(limited) //filter first five "one" strings..
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: No, stream predicates should be stateless.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, but they don't have to be: "Note also that attempting to access mutable state from behavioral parameters presents you with a bad choice with respect to safety and performance; if you do not synchronize access to that state, you have a data race and therefore your code is broken, but if you do synchronize access to that state, you risk having contention undermine the parallelism you are seeking to benefit from" - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness. OP does have to be careful using the approach in my answer, but he can.

Comment: The documentation for [`Stream.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) says it expects a "stateless predicate." I think your quote is more expository in nature.

Comment: @shmosel The quote I posted is from the link to the "stateless" condition in the filter doc you posted :) I think we agree it's not the best idea to do this. It would probably be best to create a custom `Collector` or something, but that would hide the complexity of the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.  But as already warned, predicates should be stateless.  And running this in parallel would have problems.  Although streams are popular, just because you can use them to perform a task does not always mean you should.

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("zero","one","two","three","four","five","one","one");
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
int limit = 1;
List<String> filteredWords = words.stream()
                .filter(word->!(word.equals("one") && count.incrementAndGet() <= limit))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(filteredWords);
```

Prints

```
[zero, two, three, four, five, one, one]
```

And as long as the topic came up, here is why statelessness is important in not only filters but other stream methods as well.

- fill a list with 1000 "ones", a "two", and 1000 more "ones"
- Generate two streams using the above method but in parallel, filtering out 100 one's.
- then compare the two resultant lists.

```
List<String> wordList = Stream.generate(()->"one").limit(1000)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
wordList.add("two");
wordList.addAll(Stream.generate(()->"one").limit(1000).toList());

AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
int limit = 100;
List<String> result1 = wordList.parallelStream()
        .filter(word -> !(word.equals("one")
                && count.incrementAndGet() <= limit))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

count.set(0);
List<String> result2 = wordList.parallelStream()
        .filter(word -> !(word.equals("one")
                && count.incrementAndGet() <= limit))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result1.size());
System.out.println(result2.size());
System.out.println(result1.equals(result2));
```

The sizes will be the same, but the lists will not always be equal. The only way this could happen is if some number of "ones" were removed after "two" was encountered.  Since the limit was for the `first` 100, this was clearly a problem.

Answer (score -2):

This may Help full for you check it out

```
 List<String> 
words = Arrays.asList("zero","one","two","three","four","five","one","one");

    Stream<String> sortedList =  words.stream().filter(word -> 
     word.contains("n"));

    sortedList.forEach(str->System.out.println(str));
```

Comment: How does this filter out only the first n instances of "one"?